# RouterLinkActive not working when used with *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

My **RouterLinkActive** Class is not working when I used it with the **ngFor**. I don't know where I am lagging. Below is the code I used.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mobileNavScroll" [class.leftNavOpened]="status">
    <ul role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
        <a
        routerLinkActive="active"
        routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}"
          [routerLink]="tab.routerLink"
          >{{ tab.label }}</a
        >
        <i *ngIf="tab.hasErrors" class="pi pi-info-circle tab-errors"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**.ts**

```
tabs: CommercialReportentryTabInfo[];
this.tabs = [
  {
    label: 'General Info, Land & Zoning',
    routerLink: 'general',
    component: CommercialReportentryGeninfoComponent,
    hasErrors: false
  },
  {
    label: 'Improvements',
    routerLink: 'improvements',
    component: CommercialReportentryImprovementsComponent,
    hasErrors: false
  },
]

interface CommercialReportentryTabInfo {
  label: string;
  routerLink: string;
  formGroup?: string;
  component: Function;
  hasErrors: boolean;
}
```

I have added the required modules as well. The routerLink is working fine when clicked on different tab. However, the active class is not applied to the tab

Comment: `routerLinkActiveOptions` should have been `[routerLinkActiveOptions]`

Comment: Also wonder if `routerLink: 'general',` should have been `routerLink: '/general',` , usually adds a `/` not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: it should be `[routerLink]="[tab.routerLink]"`

Comment: the issue is with the routerLinkActive class. The router Link is working fine. The class "Active" is not getting adding to the selected tab. but it is routing to the child component

Comment: If you want the tab to be active when going to a child route, then you have to remove `exact: true`, with exact set to true it will be active only when the link url exactly matches the browser url.

Comment: I am having the same issue, please can anyone help me out?